# use inheritance in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-compose

I have a lot of services, which use the same basic configuration in docker-compose. Actually most of the configuration is the same, with some minor tweaks.

I have seen that it is somehow possible to inherit values in YAML. Can I use this in docker-compose to define a "default-service" and use this all over in the other services for  e.g. `docker-compose run`? How would I do this?

Comment: Possibly start with [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Comment: Thanks i knew there was a way, i simply did not occur to me how and where to search for it

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that using YAML. The only inheritance like feature in YAML is the [Merge Key Language Independent Type](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) and that only works withing one YAML document, not between multiple documents in the same YAML file (separated by `---`) and certainly not between different YAML files.

However `docker-compose` reads `docker-compose.yml` and if available `docker-compose.override.yml`, where the values in the second file (if available) override the ones in the first. Combined with the `-f` option to specify an input YAML file for `docker-compose` you can use a shared base file with different overrides.

*This is a feature of `docker-compose` and is done on the data loaded from the YAML files, not by combining the YAML files and then loading them.*